# Cannot see LDAP group in Liferay User Groups

Tags: liferay

![enter image description here][1]I made user and group link from LDAP to Liferay. When I test in liferay, I can see LDAP user and group.

When I restart liferay server, I can see LDAP user in Liferay user, but I cannot see LDAP group in Liferay User Groups. any body help me? thank u.

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay there are two ways to import users/groups. This is controlled by the `ldap.import.method` property. This property has two possible values:

- `user` - In this case, the import will loop over all users in LDAP and, for each user, make an association to the right group (UserGroup in Liferay). For this to work correctly, each user in LDAP should have a link to his roles.
- `group` - In this case, the import will loop over all groups in LDAP and, for each group, import all users. For this to work correctly, your group memberships should be set up correctly in LDAP.

Probably, you're using a certain import method but your LDAP tree doesn't have the correct links set up?